# Increase distance between pixels in the image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bitmap, drawing

I need to enlarge an image but without resizing its pixels. 
So if primal image is just a black square, then new image should be something like it:

[image]

How could I do that?

Comment: So, basically, you want to move its pixels apart from each other, revealing a background color between them?

Comment: Collect pixel color in a 2D array and sprinkle it over a larger 2D array i.e skip (fill with BG Color) some places of larger 2d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into the [Core Image "Dot Screen"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIDotScreen) filter or other filters in the "halftone" category of core image.

If you can't find something there, you might have to build it yourself by manipulating the bitmap contents directly.